# Illegal String offset in php (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel

In lang.php file has the following array.

```
"animal" => [
           "mammel"=>[
              "cat" => "Cat",
              "ele" => "Elephant",
              "dog" => "Dog"
            ] 
        ]




$r_animal = str_ireplace($lm, trans('lang.animal.mammel')[strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3))], $r_animal);
```

In above line give the error as Illegal String offset 'ele' .

Comment: Are you looking for `trans('lang.animal.mammel.ele')`? (Btw, it's mammal)

Comment: kerbholz  - yes. I'm looking for trans('lang.animal.ele') ,  mammel is the subarray of the animal. lang is the file name.

Comment: I suppose `strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3))` does contain either `cat`, `ele` or `dog`?

Comment: substr($lm, 0, 3) returns Ele  ,

strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3)) returns ele

Answer (score 1):

To access the translations you would need something like `trans('lang.animal.mammel.cat')`, `trans('lang.animal.mammel.ele')` or `trans('lang.animal.mammel.dog')`. Assuming `strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3))` contains either "cat", "ele" or "dog" you could concatenate the required translation key like so:

```
$translationKey = 'lang.animal.mammel.' . strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3));
$r_animal = str_ireplace($lm, trans($translationKey), $r_animal);
```

Comment: Then what is the reason to return the error Illegal String offset 'ele'

Comment: You're translating `lang.animal.mammel` first, then getting the `ele`th element/char, which doesn't exist. When using `[]` on a string it'll return the char on that position (string is an array of chars): `$string = "Test"; echo $string[2];` will return `s`

Comment: No problem, please accept as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Ok, I ll check with the answer you have given.

Comment: I missed a something to told you. That is error is coming randomly. Sometimes give the right answer sometimes give the Error. I'm not yet test your answer. Can you please tell me the reason . Any other special reason than, described you previous.

Comment: Not sure without further details, have you made sure that `strtolower(substr($lm, 0, 3))` contains either "cat", "ele" or "dog" and nothing else?